# Python Code to Remove Spaces from Chinese Characters in multiple UTF8 text files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python code in Python 3.7.2 to remove spaces from all Chinese characters in multiple UTF8 text files in the same directory.

The code I have currently is applicable only to 1 file:

```
import re

with open("transcript 0623.txt") as text:
    new_text = re.sub("(?<![ -~]) (?![ -~])", "", text)
    with open("transcript 0623_out.txt", "w") as result:
        result.write(new_text)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Wave.3\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    new_text = re.sub("(?<![ -~]) (?![ -~])", "", text)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Can you advise me what is wrong and help me suggest improvements to the code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open()` returns a file object (Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

If you want to perform regex operations on the file's contents, you will have to use `.read()` function on the file object to get the text contents.

For example,

```
with open("transcript 0623.txt") as f:

    text = f.read()

    new_text = re.sub("(?<![ -~]) (?![ -~])", "", text)
    with open("transcript 0623_out.txt", "w") as result:
        result.write(new_text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. When I used the amended code, I have the following error. Can you guide me on how to amend the code to remedy this error? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Wave.3\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    text = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 444: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError usually means the encoding used in the file isn't the same one that you are using to read it. Since you mentioned these are UTF-8 files, try passing the `encoding` parameter to `open()` with the value 'utf8') i.e `open("file.txt", encoding='utf8')`

Comment: Thank you. It works for single files now. Could you suggest how I could modify the code to apply to multiple text files in the same directory?